# How to redirect different workbook specific sheet in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've got trouble with this, I need to redirect to different workbook specific sheet. Normally, can excel redirect specific sheet on same workbook only? Is there any other option to solve it?

I look forward to solve it.

Comment: Redirect as in Activate ? Bring on Top ?

Comment: Please read this in order to learn how to ask a question on here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Tell us what you tried so far, show some code, be specific what problems you may be encountering...

Answer (score 0):

To create a formula that references a different workbook, open both workbooks then create the formula in the same fashion as referencing a different worksheet in the same workbook:

1. Start entering formula
2. Switch to the other excel window (using Alt-Tab; or windows taskbar; or View tab > Switch Windows)
3. Select the cells to be referenced
4. Switch back to original window

You should get a formula that references the other workbook like:

`=[Book2.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1`